# How to add binary libraries of eccodes to pyinstaller or py2exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, py2exe, eccodes

I use Python 3.11.5 and Miniconda. I would like to create a Windows exe. The executable should display the content of the file on the console.

After creating and running the resulting executable, I get the error "Cannot find the ecCodes library". How can I add the ecCodes library?

I have installed eccodes with Conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge eccodes
conda install -c conda-forge python-eccodes
```

As described here:
[How to install ecCodes with Python Binding in Conda](https://confluence.ecmwf.int/display/UDOC/How+to+install+ecCodes+with+Python+bindings+in+conda+-+ecCodes+FAQ)

```
import xarray as xr

def load_grib2_as_xarray(file_path):
try:
  dataset = xr.open_dataset(file_path)
  return dataset
except Exception as e:
  print(f"Error loading the file: {e}")
  return None

data = load_grib2_as_xarray("E:\\Coding_Projects\\PyCharm_Workspace\\pythonProject\\Grib2_data.grib2")
print(data)
```

1. main.spec for pyIntsaller:

```
a = Analysis(
['main.py'],
pathex=[],
binaries=[],
datas=[],
hiddenimports=[],
hookspath=[],
hooksconfig={},
runtime_hooks=[],
excludes=[],
noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
pyz,
a.scripts,
[],
exclude_binaries=True,
name='main',
debug=False,
bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
strip=False,
upx=True,
console=True,
disable_windowed_traceback=False,
argv_emulation=False,
target_arch=None,
codesign_identity=None,
entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
exe,
a.binaries,
a.datas,
strip=False,
upx=True,
upx_exclude=[],
name='main',
)
```

Result: error "Cannot find the ecCodes library"

2. setup.py for py2exe:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['main.py'])
```

Result: error "Cannot find the ecCodes library"

Comment: pyinstaller analyzes what you `import` and packages only those things into the archive it creates. You're _installing_ `eccodes`, but I don't see you _importing_ it; if that happens only when the function is called, vs at module load time, then the automated analysis is liable to miss it.

Comment: ...you can use `hiddenimports` in your spec file (btw, _please_ [edit] to add indentation) to cause Python modules it doesn't detect to be added; there's a similar mechanism to explicitly add data as opposed to code that can't be autodetected.